# geocoder.getFromLocationNameshowing showing Address size 0 (Zero) in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am developing a app where i am getting location address from web service and I have show the markers on map using the address ,As we know that we have to convert address to lat,lng for that i am using following the code

Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(add, 1);

I am getting latitudes and longitudes for only few addresses,I am not getting total latitudes and longitudes.Example if i have the 29 addresses,I am getting only 19 latitudes and longitudes.

If i am using the 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="

I am getting query limit but i am getting all markers on map.

but i want use getFromLocationName method 
          geocoder.getFromLocationName(add, 1);

address like "**100 Barnes Rd Wallingford, CT 06492 USA**"
is giving me (Zero) 0 results.
 Can any one help any ideas ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably try things in the console/API explore first and then later on in android

Comment: You can not be sure that Geocoder will find coordinates of each your address